# Citroen C3 stalls when idling

Tags: stall, citroen

Mechanic changed air filter and crank sensor, to no avail. He says further tests might be quite costy. Any suggestion as to what could cause this problem?

Codes: P1336 (crank sensor) and also P0204 (injector)

Comment: Did he read the codes before doing anything? Has he checked for air leaks?

Comment: I just collected the car, mechanic gave me the code I added to my question

Comment: So the codes have just been read ? If do, then either they have not been cleared or the crank sensor or wiring is still defective...

Comment: The engine autodiagnosis system lamp went off after a few days without me doing anything. First the car stopped stalling while idling when car was cold. Then it stopped stalling altogether with the warning lamp now off. I suppose this should narrow down the problem a little bit as to the probable cause?

Comment: Correction, it does it again. Very capricious issue it seems.